# @Transactional timeout default value

Tags: timeout, spring-transactions

In Spring documentation, it is given that Spring JpaTransactionManager default time out is -1. So if we are not manually specifying any @Transactional timeout, it is expected to take default timeout value(-1). What does it mean? Exactly after how many seconds will the transaction timeout?

Answer (score 0):

It won't timeout at all. If the connection to DB freezes, you will get transactions lasting hours.
See, for ex., `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager`

```java
int timeout = determineTimeout(definition);
if (timeout != TransactionDefinition.TIMEOUT_DEFAULT) {
    txObject.getConnectionHolder().setTimeoutInSeconds(timeout);
}

protected int determineTimeout(TransactionDefinition definition) {
    if (definition.getTimeout() != TransactionDefinition.TIMEOUT_DEFAULT) {
        return definition.getTimeout();
    }
    return this.defaultTimeout;
}
```

where `TransactionDefinition.TIMEOUT_DEFAULT` is `-1`